# C# - How to match a value that might contain the matching pattern itself in regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a huge list of messages that are formatted like this in a raw text:

```
[Date(m/d/y)], [time(nn:nn AM/PM)] - [name] : [message],
```

Example:

```
9/15/17, 12:33 PM - Brian Bouman: Hey,
```

Is there anyway to extract all the things between brackets even though the message and name may contain them as well?

Them being `,` `:` and `-`

Comment: Very simple, the date is always till the first ',', after this the time - till the '-', the name is till the latest ':' and after that the message..

Comment: If you want to generate a regex I think you can use [Xeger](https://code.google.com/p/xeger/) -HTH ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be pretty straight forward

```
^(?<date>.*), (?<time>.*) - (?<name>.*): (?<message>.*),$
```

explanation:

`^(?<date>.*)`, matches the date, anything in between the start of the line and the first comma.

`(?<time>.*) -` matches the time, anything between the space and the character "-"

`(?<name>.*):` matches the name, everything from where we are to the next ":"

`(?<message>.*),$` matches the message, everything from where we are to "," and the end of file/line.

Answer (score 1):

I think your pattern instead of `[Date(m/d/y)], [time(nn:nn AM/PM)] - [name] : [message],` should be `[Date(m/d/y)], [time(nn:nn AM/PM)] - [name]: [message],` - no space after `[name]` - So a way is this:

```
// A dynamic pattern is given
var pattern = @"[Date(m/d/y)], [time(nn:nn AM/PM)] - [name]: [message],";    

// in patternMaps; I make pattern conventions
var patternMaps = new Dictionary<string, string>
                      {
                          { "[mdy]", @"\d\d?" },   // I will replace `m`,`d`,`y`s between parentheses to accept one or two digits  
                          { "n", @"\d" },          // I will replace `n`s between parentheses to accept one digit only
                          { @"AM/PM", "(AM|PM)" }, // I will replace `AM/PM` between parentheses to accept `AM` or `PM`
                          { "[/]", @"\/" }         // I will replace `/` between parentheses to `\/` for removing regex exception
                      };

// `parts` contains name and patterns between brackets
var parts =
    Regex.Matches(pattern, @"\[(?<part>[^(\]]+)(\((?<pattern>[^)]+)\))?]")
        .OfType<Match>()
        .ToDictionary(
            k => k.Groups["part"].ToString(),
            v => v.Groups["pattern"].ToString());

// Applying patternMaps to patterns
parts = patternMaps.Aggregate(
    parts,
    (current, pm) => current.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => Regex.Replace(v.Value, pm.Key, pm.Value)));

// generate fit pattern for creating a proper regex
var regexPattern = Regex.Replace(
    Regex.Replace(pattern, @"\([^)]+\)", string.Empty),
    @"\[(?<part>[^]]+)\]",
    c =>
        {
            var part = parts.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Key == c.Groups["part"].ToString());
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(part.Value) ? $@"(?<{part.Key}>[\w ]+)" : $@"(?<{part.Key}>{part.Value})";
        });

var message = "9/15/17, 12:33 PM - Brian Bouman: Hey,";

// Applying generated pattern to message
var result = Regex.Match(message, $"^{regexPattern}$");  // "^...$" means whole - from the beginning to the end pf - the string

if (result.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"## Message matched##: {message}");

    foreach (var part in parts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{part.Key}: {result.Groups[$"{part.Key}"]}");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Message not matched!: {message}");
}
```

[**C# Fiddle Demo**](http://rextester.com/FSNYC81434)

Actually, at first I generate a regex from a given pattern, then I apply it over a message to gather each part -HTH ;).